# printing a textarea from a form

Tags: html, printing

I'm in the process of printing an HTML form. After checking via the internet, I am unable to print all the input. Here's what I have now:

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function CopyElem(elem)
  {
      $('form input[type=text]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
      });
 
      $('form input[type=date]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
      });
 
      $('form input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
      });
 
  }
  function PrintElem(elem)
  {
      Popup($(elem).html());
  }
 
  function Popup(data) 
  {
      var mywindow = window.open('', 'myfrm');
      mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Behandelformulier</title>'); 
      mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
      mywindow.document.write(data);
      mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
 
      mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
      mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
 
      mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();
 
      return true;
  }
```

`
only it does not print the content of the "input type="textarea". You won't see it in print preview either. What am I doing wrong?

I've been searching the internet for days, but can't find anything about it.

Comment: When you go through each of the form fields in `CopyElem()`, you only seem to gather `text`, `date` and `checkbox` field types. Is that why? Do you need to separately address `$('form input[type=textarea]').each(function() {` perhaps? I'm not familiar with JS so I'm not actually sure what some of the code does, especially as you don't seem to call `CopyElem()` anywhere.

Comment: You provide three function not connected to each other - please add more information.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for my problem.
In the function `CopyElem(elem)` I placed

```js
function CopyElem(elem) {
    $('form textarea').each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).val());
    });
}
```